# NodeJs Axios Website Requested Webpage HTML Response is Unreadable

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm trying to request a webpage and run it through `cheerio`, but the response HTML is not readable and is made up of characters like `�a��{t��`.

How do I receive a readable response?

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

axios.get('https://www.amazon.co.uk/Acer-XF243YPbmiiprx-Monitor-FreeSync-Adjustable/dp/B097F6DT45')
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            console.log($.html())
        }
    }, (error) => console.log(err));
```

What I receive:

```
�Sn����M�٠��g���+=�������&x��.�@!�Q36�%�[�H�+ݴ�|��_/��d�8_
K�b&E�_�}[U1�@u梅Y����{T6ǞOrt��q���ri����eJ(���w����~}S�
    �4/��&�2�y���X, �Ǥ���0b�n��PS6O��kY��=�2k�Z��K�Z��r�t
    A4�����c���vnY�{t���u�_���C��C&��u����W)���He���O�X��
        �]P�
    ��Ѐ�(�?�,y�m����b��|6���B�|�l6��ݻ+&�6�/vH�O�oX�;�X�s 
    [����I��&��U �����v�=�vR{��֥����L�r��tG�l�ܓY�N)����(
        �(����qX���Z=f�b�-�����At舮�^U6���ف{�h�w�p���m��ϝ
```

In my attempts to fix I tried to reencode the response to `utf-8`. I also requesting from `http` instead of `https`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazone simply block basic web scrapping made by programs without header and more, severals conditions can trigger their protections (resulting by sending garbages),
see more with [Gidon Lev Eli's answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-Amazon-block-web-scraping).

You can still bypass it by making your program interacting with Amazon more "like a true browser" than "a mere headless script".